# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains' when applying a function to a df column using Lambda

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column based on the following logic by using the function below. When I apply this function to a df using lambda, I am seeing the following error. I tried to remove the "str" in front of "contains" but it did not work. Could anyone assist or advise? Thanks.

```
def new_col(x):
    if pd.isna(x):
        return ''
    elif x.str.contains('Watch',case=False):
        return 'Product A'
    elif x.str.contains('Glasses',case=False):
        return 'Product B'
    elif x.str.contians('Table',case=False):
        return 'Product C'
    elif x.str.contains('Computer',case=False):
        return 'Product D'
    elif x.str.contains('Beauty',case=False):
        return 'Product E'
    elif x.str.contains(','):
        return x.split(',')[0]
    else:
        return x

df['new column'] = df.apply(lambda x: new_col(x['product']),axis=1)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Comment: should `contians` be `contains`?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I did the typing instead of copy and paste because pasting content to a website is prohibited when I am using the corporate laptop.

Comment: The thing is, using `lambda x `is performing operation to every row in your column. `str.contains` is only applicable to a series.

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew, that makes lots of sense. Can you give me some advice on how to fix this or what would the alternative solution would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.contains` is a function applicable to a series as a whole. In your case, instead of using Pandas functions, you can use a simple for loop to do the trick.

```
result = []

for i in df['product']:
    if pd.isna(i):
        result.append('')
    elif 'watch' in i.lower():
        result.append('Product A')
    elif 'glasses' in i.lower():
        result.append('Product B')
    elif 'table' in i.lower():
        result.append('Product C')
    elif 'computer' in i.lower():
        result.append('Product D')
    elif 'beauty' in i.lower():
        result.append('Product E')
    elif ',' in i:
        result.append(i.split(',')[0])
    else:
        result.append(i)

df['new column'] = result
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For everything that’s fall outside of this condition, there are cases like “fruit,vegetables, meat”. In such case, I would need to take the first string before the comma which is fruit. And there are also something like “fruit”, “vegetable” ,in case such , take the value as is

Comment: Is this what you need?

Comment: I see your updated solution. This’s great. The only problem is that condition is the last condition, shouldn’t be the first condition before the loop.

Comment: In that case, it is easier as you can put it at the last in the for loop :D

Comment: Absolutely! Your helps and the solution are fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `in` operator with [`str.casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) to perform a case-insensitive substring search:

```
def new_col(x):
    if pd.isna(x):
        return ''
    elif 'Watch'.casefold() in x.str.casefold():
        return 'Product A'
    elif 'Glasses'.casefold() in x.str.casefold():
        return 'Product B'
    elif 'Table'.casefold() in x.str.casefold():
        return 'Product C'
    elif 'Computer'.casefold() in x.str.casefold():
        return 'Product D'
    elif 'Beauty'.casefold() in x.str.casefold():
        return 'Product E'
    elif ',' in x.str:
        return x.split(',')[0]
    else:
        return x
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried this and still have AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'